# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xxx'; 'xxx' is not a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, package

I am creating a project called OpenCity which contains a premium version. The premium package is the problem.

The project hierarchy is:

```
opencity // is a project in PyCharm 2019.3
      premium // is a package
             __init__.py // is a module
             premium.py // is a module
             premium_user.py // is a module
             premium_user.txt // is a text file
```

premium_user.py:

```
import random as ran


def premium_users_adder():
    premium_user1a = open('premium_user.txt', 'a')
    # premium_user1w = open('premium_user.txt', 'w')
    # premium_user1r = open('premium_user.txt', 'r')
    p2 = int(input("How many members do you want to add to premium_users to database? "))
    p1 = []
    p3 = []
    for i in range(p2):
        member = input("Type the person's name. ")
        p1.append(member)
        id1 = ran.randint(100000000, 99999999999)
        p3.append(str(id1))
    for i, e in zip(p1, p3):
        premium_user1a.write(i + ' ' + e + '\n')
    premium_user1a.close()
    print()
    print("Done")


def premium_users_checker():
    premium_user1r = open('premium_user.txt', 'r')
    p2 = []
    for data in premium_user1r:
        p2.append(data)
        print(p2)
```

premium.py:

```
import premium.premium_users as pu
pu.premium_users_adder()
pu.premium_users_checker()
```

Error when running premium.py:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/PyCharm Python Works/OpenCity/premium/premium.py", line 1, in <module>
    import premium.premium_users as pu
  File "F:\PyCharm Python Works\OpenCity\premium\premium.py", line 1, in <module>
    import premium.premium_users as pu
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'premium.premium_users'; 'premium' is not a package
```

I have given everything except the `premium_users.txt` which contains premium codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These errors occur because your local module named `premium.py` shadows the installed premium module you are trying to use. The current directory is prepended to `sys.path`, so the local name takes precedence over the installed name (You can read more about **how python finds packages** [**here**](https://leemendelowitz.github.io/blog/how-does-python-find-packages.html)).

An extra debugging tip when this comes up is to look at the Traceback carefully, and realize that the name of your script in question is matching the module you are trying to import:

Notice the name you used in your script:

```
File "F:/PyCharm Python Works/OpenCity/premium/premium.py", line 1, in <module>
```

The module you are trying to import: `premium`

Rename your module to something else to avoid the name collision.

Python may generate a `premium.pyc` file next to your `premium.py` file (in the `__pycache__` directory in Python 3). Remove that as well after your rename, as the interpreter will still reference that file, reproducing the error. However, the `pyc` file in `__pycache__` should not affect your code if the py file has been removed.

Comment: Thank you this fixed me.
But I got another problem.

Comment: @sairamkumar happy to hear that. What is the current issue?

Comment: I fixed that myself

Comment: @EyalGolan, Thanks man, that was a very hard lesson for me, took a while to find a fix.

Comment: @MohabKhaled Happy to hear my answer helped you. Fixing such issues can be frustrating, but you learn from them and hopefully will take less time to solve such bugs in the future :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `from` then `import` any module

do this-

```
from premium import premium_users as pu
```

instead of-

```
import premium.premium_users as pu
```

Comment: from premium import premium_users as pu